# Convert NSString to FBSDKAccessToken

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook

Is there anyway to convert my NSString access token to type FBSDKAccessToken? I need it to be of this form to perform login with Facebook and Parse:

```
[PFFacebookUtils logInInBackgroundWithAccessToken:AccessToken
    block:^(PFUser *user, NSError *error) {
        if (!user) {
            NSLog(@"Uh oh. There was an error logging in.");
        } else {
            NSLog(@"User logged in through Facebook!");
            NSLog(@"%@", user);
        }
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is a simple login as you have in your example you shouldn't need to do it at all, and instead just call `+currentAccessToken`.
But if you actually want to create it, you can just initialize a new AccessToken and pass it in the request

```
- (instancetype)
initWithTokenString: (NSString *)tokenString
        permissions: (NSArray *)permissions
declinedPermissions: (NSArray *)declinedPermissions
              appID: (NSString *)appID
             userID: (NSString *)userID
     expirationDate: (NSDate *)expirationDate
        refreshDate: (NSDate *)refreshDate
                     NS_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER;
```

> This initializer should only be used for advanced apps that manage
>   tokens explicitly. Typical login flows only need to use
>   FBSDKLoginManager along with +currentAccessToken.

find more [in the Facebook documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/current/class/FBSDKAccessToken/).